# C++ & Python: Concurrency, Embedding and Extensions

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, tree

My project entails the need for a heavily threaded AVL Tree. Obviously this is not possible to do efficiently in Python due to the GIL, but in C++ this is a piece of cake. As the tree will be receiving data which needs to be preprocessed and analyzed, it would be preferable to write as much in Python as possible.

There are 3 main 'functions' that will need to run concurrently.

1 3rd party API event based data stream which analyzes data and inserts it into the tree

2 Tree validation and re-balancing

3 Querying the data in the structure (eg: find_all(desired_data_type))

The current plan is to write a Python Extension Module which implements this threaded tree in C++, but the problem is the concurrency with the API streams. These would be much nicer to code in Python as the data analytics support is so nice. Hence there is a need for python scripts that are embedded into the C++ tree module and run on separate interpreters which are able to call the insert functions in the tree module that initialized them? A bit like writing a method in the tree extension module that takes an argument equivalent to the name of a python module to be imported, then runs that on a new interpreter so we can just add scripts to the threaded C++ tree with new API data sources when needed.

EDIT: Question simplification

Can i write a C++ program that spawns a Python Interpreter and script where the python script is able to call a method in that original C++ program?

Comment: There are many architectures you could use.  If the C++ is running in a different process, then you don't need to write a python extension.  You could pass python values using some IPC mechanism, like sockets, named pipes, message queues, etc. You still need to worry about converting python values to C++ and back, but there are mechanisms like pack/unpack, or even JSON or YAML.  Whether this is sensible depends a lot on data structure and volumes.

Comment: It seems what you really want is a c++ program that can invoke python scripts buy the other way around. This is doable - you can initialize several python interpreters in c++ and call functions in them. Depending on the code you may want to do both things: a c++ program that initializes the python interpreters and make your avl tree (first person ever to describe a well scaling concurrent avl tree a piece of cake to implement I think ;) ) a python module.

Comment: Note though that multiple interprets are a rarely executed code path with all that entails and that calling python from c++ is generally really ugly. I'd definitely see first if you could go with an IPC solution - I did something similar to what you're thinking about for a hobby project and regretted it later due to all the complications.

Comment: Thanks guys I am definitely looking at IPC right now, but making the AVL tree in python is out of the question(?) as the tree has to concurrently be inserted into and queried as the data volume is massive (terabytes of text analyzed a day) and delay between queries tiny. Do you think I would be better off with IronPython and C#? No GIL and thread abstraction etc?